# Subject-verb agreement of singular-plural

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> **Top of mind** on Capitol Hill as lawmakers return from recess this week **are** the annual spending bills to keep the government open, which must be enacted by the time the new fiscal year starts on Oct. 1. - [The Wall Street Journal 2023. 6. 10.](https://www.wsj.com/articles/congress-dives-back-into-fights-on-spending-cuts-military-as-deadline-draws-nears-c9fcee?st=x3hc7h7ix5v3iex&reflink=desktopwebshare_permalink)

I understand the skeleton of the above as *top of mind are the annual spending bills to keep the govenrment open*. If so why is the subject *top* but not *tops*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Top of mind” is an idiom meaning “occupying one’s thoughts”, or “of greatest priority”.

As an idiom, it is a set phrase, and it would be odd to change it to “minds”.

But notice also that you have identified “top of mind” as the subject of the verb “are”, but this sentence actually demonstrates subject-verb inversion: the subject of the verb “are” is “annual spending bills”, which is plural.

If I was analysing the sentence, I would read it as “The annual spending bills are top of mind(ie. of greatest priority)”.

Subject-verb inversion is used as a form of emphasis, because it elevates the importance of the subject. In this case, the “annual spending bills”, which are the main topic of the news article.

Answer (score 1):

It could be construed as, "The annual spending bills are [on] the top of mind." That said, to me this is awkward English usage, perhaps *intended* to make it sound different. Also, why not, "minds?"